# Unable to save or open with Macbook pro and ubuntu

Tags: macbook

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on Macbook pro (2010) and sadly I have not found any solutions to the problem.

Whenever I try to open or save a file in any application it locks down that application window by darkening it right away. I can unlock this state by pressing esc button.

Does this problem relate on file permission?

BR
Wintha

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution from: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395250 and now it works fine!